# How to Identify Angular 2 Code written in HTML to be rendered using innerHTML of a div?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

There is no better way to frame the question but:

I have a button in my Application:

```
<div #displayDiv></div>
<button (click)="genTable()"></button>
```

The function call in the component is as follows:

```
@ViewChild('displayDiv') div: ElementRef;
.
.
genTable(): void {
  this.div.nativeElement.innerHTML = ''; // clear the contents of the div
  // Make some API call and get data in JSON format and store it
  // in a private variable of the class called tableResult

  // change content of div using innerHTML
  this.div.nativeElement.innerHTML = `
    <table>
     <tr *ngFor="let eachProp of tableResult">
      <th>{{eachProp}}</th>
     </tr>
    </table>
  `;
}
```

The above code just shows **`{{eachProp}}`** as a string and not its content plus it is shown only once.

How do I make the `*ngFor` and the Angular templates viz. `{{eachProp}}` dynamically available when writing code within the `innerHTML` of the div?

#### Further Info

I already am rendering some Diagram in the `displayDiv` and once when the user clicks the button, the diagram is cleared off and a table is displayed based on the JSON response from a server.

**JSON Response**:

```
    {"input":{"concept":"HighChair",
     "parameters":["hasHeight","hasWidth"],
      "filters":[{"min":3.0,"max":5.2}]},
      "columns":["hasHeight","hasWidth"],
      "rows":[["106.0","47.0"],["85.0","50.0"]]}
```

Comment: You do not need to change the element directly. That is not the way Angular is supposed to be used. I will try provide an answer.

Comment: Don't program this way.

Comment: You would have to do something like dynamic component. That way, when you click on a button it would compile the component during runtime.

Comment: @12seconds any hints on dynamic components would be appreciated

Comment: See angular doc on dynamic component loader https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Answer (score 2):

```
<div>
  <table *ngIf="tableResult">
    <tr>
      <th *ngFor="let eachProp of tableResult?.columns">{{eachProp}}</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let row of tableResult?.rows">
      <td *ngFor="let field of row">
        {{field}}
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <div *ngIf="!tableResult">
     <!-- put your initial diagram here -->
  </div>
</div>
<button (click)="genTable()"></button>
```

And in the component, something like this:

```
/* typescript */
tableResult: any;
genTable(): void {
    this.tableResult = this.someService.fetchResults();
}
```

Comment: I understand this. and this is a standard way of doing it, but I already have a Diagram that is rendered on the `#displayDiv` and the button needs to show the content in the same div by removing it.

Comment: I guess I do not understand your question enough then, sorry. As mentioned, just try not to update HTML by accessing any DOM element directly, instead let Angular handle DOM manipulation.

Comment: made some edits according to the given JSON. This however is a temporary solution. because everytime if i want to render a new diagram it wont since `tableResult` will still exist

Comment: Then just do `this.tableResult = null`, so that the table gets hidden again.

Comment: where should that be put?

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to know from your code what's in tableResult but I suspect that's what's causing your error. A suggestion would be try to do {{ tableResult }} right below the table tag. That way you can see if its content is correct and if it is an array or collection that can be iterated by *ngFor.

** EDIT: As other users have pointed out, you are trying to insert an uncompiled element to the DOM. That's not going to fly. You need to have a template and do things in your template. see here: https://angular.io/guide/architecture#templates

Comment: This is not the error. The error is that inserted HTML is not Angular template code, and will not be interpreted as such.

Comment: @MarioMatos `tableResult` is a JSON response from the server. I can show it in div once the the JSON is stored and if I do `.innerHTML=JSON.stringify(this.tableResult)`